# Java 8 - sort a Collection of Objects by a property with an order defined in an array

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have the following Class:

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Foo setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Foo setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a couple of `Foo` objects in `Collection<Foo> fooCollection` and the String Array `String[] names`.

Now I want to order `fooCollection` by the property `name`, in the same order the `name` Strings are ordered in `names`.

How do I do that using Java 8 Stream?

Comment: How does that involve the `names` array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(f.getName())` as comparison key:

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(names);
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>(fooCollection);
fooList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(f -> nameList.indexOf(f.getName())));
```

Or if you definitely want Stream API:

```
List<Foo> fooList = fooCollection.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(f -> nameList.indexOf(f.getName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However if you have many names, you may consider making this more efficient, preparing first a reverse index of names:

```
Map<String, Integer> nameMap = IntStream.range(0, names.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(idx -> names[idx], Function.identity()));
List<Foo> fooList = fooCollection.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(f -> nameMap.get(f.getName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I assume that all the names are different and every `Foo` has the corresponding name in the `names` array.

Comment: Thanks, I think the stream api version of it solves exactly my problem!

Comment: How to preserve the type <Collection> and not a List<>??

Answer (score 0):

First you build a `Comparator` from the `names` array using the [static factory methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#method.summary), e.g. via a [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) over the array. Then you pass the comparator to `stream.sort`

Comment: Could you give a code example for the comparator? Not sure how to do it

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff Check the comments in the code i posted

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the `String[]` to a `List<String>` to take advantage of the `indexOf` method. Then you compare the equivalent indexes of `Foo.name` in your new names List using the `Comparator<T>` interface. I made the entire code so you can copy it and run it:

```
package io.github.gabrielbb.java.utilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel Basilio Brito
 * @since 27-12-16
 */
public class CollectionSortingBasedOnArray {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person("Donald", "Trump"));
        personList.add(new Person("Gabriel", "Basilio"));
        personList.add(new Person("Chris", "Brown"));
        personList.add(new Person("Barack", "Obama"));

        String[] sortedNames = {"Barack", "Chris", "Donald", "Gabriel"};
        List<String> sortedNamesList = Arrays.asList(sortedNames); // Converting Array to List to take advantage of "indexOf" method

        Collections.sort(personList, (Person p1, Person p2) -> { // Using the Comparator<T> interface with Lambda Expression
            Integer n1 = sortedNamesList.indexOf(p1.getName()); // Get the position of the first person name in the Names List (before an Array)
            Integer n2 = sortedNamesList.indexOf(p2.getName()); // Get the position of the second person name in the Names List
            return n1.compareTo(n2); // Now is simple: Just compare those indexes.
        });

        // Collections.sort lines can be replaced with: personList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> sortedNamesList.indexOf(p.getName())));

        personList.stream().forEach((p) -> {
            System.out.println(p.getName() + " " + p.getLastName()); // Print each Person Information
        });
    }
}

class Person {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Collections.sort lines are for better understanding of what is happening behind but it can be replaced with:

```
personList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> sortedNamesList.indexOf(p.getName())));
```

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while, but you can shorten the comparison like

```
List fooSortedByName = new ArrayList(fooCollection);
fooSortedByName.sort(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getName));
```

Comment: I think this answer doesn't answer what has been asked. The request was to sort `fooCollection` by the order of names in `names`.

Comment: You're right, ```List.copyOf()``` returns an immutable list, I changed it to use an ArrayList, and now it's basically the acceptedx answer ;-)

Comment: It's not. The accepted answer sorts by a name list that is separate from `fooCollection`. You just sort by the name field.